# Apex Quick Start -- How do I use the Book?

Tags: apex

I just tried the Apex Quick Start guide, which I found here:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm

As part of that Quick Start, I created a kind of Hello World Apex class; my class represents a Book.  The Book object has a name and a price.

My problem is, I don't know how to use it.  I guess I want to be able to enter Book records someplace, just like I would create a Case or a Contact?

By the way...I'm not aware that I've deployed my Apex code.  I don't have a production environment, only a development one.

Answer (score 0):

The example in the guide only creates the `Book` object but doesn't really highlight in details as how you can use it from UI, i.e., by creating a Tab, page layout, etc. So to directly answer your question, you will need to create a tab for the object and then use that to create records.

But, if you are really looking to learn more around Apex and Custom Objects or any topic within Salesforce in general, you should then head to [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/home). Trailhead is a great resource to learn. It provides you with an opportunity to practice while you are learning. You will always be able to verify what you have learned using the hands-on challenge. And you don't need any specific environment, you can use the Trailhead Playgrounds to test out the challenges.

If you are specifically looking to learn Custom Objects and Apex, then you should start from these modules, and then you can always return to the Apex Developer Guide for details.

- [Data Modeling](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_modeling)
- [Apex Basics & Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database)